# I need to add a default value (null or blank) to xml query in SSRS

Tags: xml, wcf, reporting-services

In an SSRS report I have a parameter query that has a data source that is the field names from a shared data set.

Data Source:

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx/GetItemDefinition?<path to data set>&rs:Command=GetDataSetDefinition
```

I get the field names using an xml query of the data set like so:

```
<Query >
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">SharedDataSet {}/DataSet {}/Fields {}/Field</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I am using the field names for dynamic grouping in the SSRS report so I can select the grouping as a parameter. The fields are coming back as expected but I would also like to allow a blank value as default.

It appears I need to join the blank value in the query and allow blanks to be able to set it. If this was SQL I would just do a UNION to get the default value.

It is possible to to accomplish the same thing in the xml query in SSRS?